# How do I abstract querying in the MongoDB C# Driver v2?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

So I used to be able to run Linq queries against the `MongoCollection` through `IQueryable` in version 1.x

When I'm referencing my db libraries, since all I'm doing is exposing the `IQueryable` interface, my calling code never needed to reference any of the C# driver stuff. It seems like I need to manually map my queries now, or expose the filter definition. Is there a "right" way to do this? (easy to read/easy to maintain)

Comment: You could wait for the next version that will support IQueryable<>? :-) https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/CSHARP-935 it should be present in v2.1

Answer (score 2):

I suggest simply not abstracting over the driver.

You can't really use LINQ and exchange the underlying DB and expect everything to work anyway.

As was suggested by xanatos in the comments, you can wait for the driver to add support for LINQ in v2.1, but keep in mind that LINQ is synchronous and the driver isn't. That means that you will either block on `async` code ([which is bad](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html)) or you would use the driver's special `async` methods (which isn't really an abstraction)

Maintaining the abstraction seems not to be worth the effort in my opinion.